# Win10 diskpart FAILs to format a partition/volume, why?

Tags: windows-10, diskpart

Briefly speaking, when I execute the following 3 commands upon a new disk,

```
convert gpt

create partition efi size=442

format fs=fat32 quick
```

Windows 10 (1909 in my case) blames that:

> DiskPart has encountered an error: The parameter is incorrect.
>
> See the System Event Log for more information.

I open up eventvwr.msc but cannot see any entries saying the error reason. Why is it so?

Later, I confirm that creating a mere "Primary" partition(no need to be EFI system partition) exhibits the same problem. It seems that I have convicted a low-level novice error.

The same commands works OK on Windows 7, but fails on Windows 10. No clue what happens, please help.

[image: OK on Win7 SP1]

[image: Fail on Win10]

==== Updates ====

[Diskpart, sub-command filesystem says nothing special.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzq0f.png)

```
DISKPART> filesys

Current File System

  Type                 : RAW
  Allocation Unit Size : 512
  Flags : 00000000

File Systems Supported for Formatting

  Type                 : NTFS (Default)
  Allocation Unit Sizes: 512, 1024, 2048, 4096 (Default), 8192, 16K, 32K, 64K, 128K, 256K, 512K, 1024K, 2048K

  Type                 : FAT
  Allocation Unit Sizes: 8192 (Default), 16K, 32K, 64K

  Type                 : FAT32
  Allocation Unit Sizes: 512, 1024, 2048, 4096 (Default)
```

Comment: Does the [`FILESYSTEMS`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/filesystems) command in diskpart tell you anything useful?

Comment: It says nothing special, still no clue. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzq0f.png